# C#: code style - places for members

Tags: c#, .net, coding-style

I know that private fields are first. Where should be placed other members according to C# code-style?

I mean: private/protected/internal/public fields/properties/methods/events.
I always placed events at the last part of class. I sometimes place private method near public property that use it. I don't think it is right location, but i can't choose the place for it and for a lot of other members.

Comment: Download a copy of [StyleCop](http://stylecop.codeplex.com/) if you wish to be nagged by issues like this. Otherwise, do whatever you want or whatever the rest of your team does. Questions like this about coding style are subjective, and not likely to produce a universal consensus.

Comment: @GAPS - it does matter, but only inside the scope of the project or team.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to StyleCop (the style checker made by Microsoft), the correct ordering  is:

> Adjacent elements of the same type
>   must be positioned in the following
>   order by access level:
>
> - public
>
>   internal
>
>   protected internal
>
>   protected
>
>   private
>
> - *Rule SA1202*

You might also be interested in rule SA1201, which deals with the order of the types of elements (ie. Fields go first, then constructors, ...).

To read more about the StyleCop Rules Guide go here: http://stylecop.codeplex.com/releases/view/44839

Answer (score 4):

This is an example of [coding guidelines](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brada/archive/2005/01/26/361363.aspx) (see towards the end, "File organization"). There are many and not all agree on the order of class members.

As a matter of personal preference, I prefer grouping constants, fields, properties, constructors, members (public first, then internal, then protected, then private) in this order using #region - #endregion blocks.

The reason why I leave private members for last is that when I read code, I like to get the information of the class's interface to the outside world before knowing how it implements it in private members.

Answer (score 1):

Classes should be organized into regions within an application using a layout determined

by your application architect. These may be based on accessibility, type, or functionality. Consult your architect for the layout strategy used in your application.

Example:

```
// Class layout based on accessibility
class Purchasing
{
    #region Main

    #region Public

    #region Internal

    #region Protected

    #region Private

    #region Extern

    #region Designer Generated Code
}
```

Guidelines:

o   Use the same layout consistently in all classes in an application.

o   Omit regions if their associated class elements are not needed.

o   The Designer Generated Code region created by Visual Studio’s Visual Designer should never be modified by hand. It should contain only code generated by the designer.

Comment: Regions are good for generated code. Otherwise, IMO they only clutter the content of the code. When opening a class, you're always looking for what the class contains and does. Having to expand a bunch of regions before you get to the code only introduces friction. Also, the members scopes is already documented by their scoping keyword, thus regions doesn't add any value other than their (dubious) grouping value.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer

- private
- protected
- public

I think there isn't much you can do wrong in that kind of code style.

Comment: So, you at first write all private members (fields, properties, methods, events), then you write protected fields, properties, methods etc. Isn't it?

Comment: Just to demonstrate how incredibly subjective questions like this are, I have to disagree with your proposed organizational system. It's far more useful to see the public interface of a class *first* when browsing its code file. That would imply that the private members should always be placed *last*, as they're the least likely to be important to someone who reads the code.

Answer (score 0):

Do what ever feels right for you - just be consistent.

Answer (score 0):

I think that, unless you make a mess of your code messing everything and putting it all together, you can choose which order you prefer.

As long as you are consistent with it, there is no correct order.